# Can anyone explain the behavior of this function?

Tags: functions, polar-coordinates

I inserted the function $r=\sin(\theta/v)$, where $v$ was an adjustable constant. Upon reaching each number, it gave a very interesting graph. The way Desmos works is to prevent overflow, it allows you to specify the highest number $\theta$ can be, in units of $\pi$. When the value of $v$ exceeded the upper limit of $\theta$ divided by $\pi$, the graph devolved into an ever-shrinking spiral. To further visualize, here are some graphs. In all of these, the highest value of $\theta$ is $100\pi$.[image] When the value of $v$ is less than $100$, there is no spiral. But when it is greater than $100$ (like $1000$ shown here), it devolves into a packed spiral. Can anyone explain why this function behaves this way?

Comment: Is that $\frac{\sin\theta}{v}$ or $\sin\frac{\theta}{v}$? Clarify by editing your question.

Comment: its sin(theta/v).

Answer (score 2):

The graph $r=\theta$ looks like a spiral.

For $\theta$ small, $\sin \theta \approx \theta$.  There is a trade-off between the value of $v$ and how far out you plot it.  Eventually, this approximation breaks down and the graph no longer looks like a spiral.

Comment: But the exact opposite is happening. Why does that happen?

Comment: @NipDip "When the value of $v$ is less than 100, there is no spiral." Because small $v$ implies "large" $\theta/v$, so $\sin(\theta/v) \not\approx \theta/v$. It's when $v$ is "large" (here, 1000) that we get "small" $\theta/v$ and $\sin(\theta/v) \approx \theta/v$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ r = \sin\frac{\theta}{v}$$

By differentiation

Radial component of spiral

$$ \Delta r =  \frac{\Delta \theta}{v}\cos\frac{\theta}{v}$$

Circumferential component

$$ r \Delta {\theta}= \Delta \theta \sin\frac{\theta}{v}$$

At high $\theta$ spiral increments gets close. At low $\theta$ there is a larger radial component.